# ASP.NET MVC Page not render when specify action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, master-pages

I'm having the following problem in my application.
When access a view, specifying only the controller, the entire layout of the master page is rendered correctly:
Eg: 
localhost:50904/Contact

[image]

But when I specify the action, the layout of the master page is not rendered:
Eg: 
localhost:50904/Contact/Index
localhost:50904/Contact/Success

[image]

I checked the HTML generated in both cases, and the generated HTML is correct. What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have references to .css files and those references are relative.  Change the references to the .css files to start with / to make them rooted to the root of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Press F12 and look for any errors in the console or network tabs.

You my find that the css or js files are not loading, check the paths if you see any errors.